# SVG element appears to have arbitrary height

Tags: html, svg

I've been really trying to learn some SVG. But browsers seem to get in a right old muddle rendering it.

Take the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00"/>
    </svg>
    <p>Hello? Hellooooooooooooo?</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

View this is any modern browser and you'll see an arbitrary amount of whitespace between the rectangle and the following HTML paragraph. (IE9 doesn't display anything but noone will be surprised about that.)

Firefox (Firebug) doesn't give the heights of either the `svg` or the `rect` elements. It just wimps out and says 'auto'.

Opera says the `svg` has a height of 150px and says 'auto' for the `rect`.

Chrome mans up and gives heights for both. 102px for the `rect` (obviously including the stroke) and 428px for the `svg`.

My expectation is that the `svg` element would be a 'thin' container (i.e. add nothing to the dimensions of its contents) and therefore have a height of 102px.

Anyone know what the correct behaviour should be and how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: Could the downvoter explain themselves?

Comment: Ah. 2 downvotes. No explanation or suggestion. Trolls?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've not explicitly defined what the width or height of the SVG is, or where the rectangle is placed, or even what part of the SVG is of interest.  It's hardly surprising browsers are dealing with things differently.

Try defining a width and height:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="102px" height="102px">
  <rect height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00"/>
</svg>
```

Alternatively, define a `viewBox`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 102 102">
  <rect height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00"/>
</svg>
```

Or both:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-50 -50 52 52" width="102px" height="102px">
  <rect height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00"/>
</svg>
```

[Here are some examples in action](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/54EQ2/).

Comment: Thank you robertc. So do I have to calculate the dimensions of the drawings inside the `svg` element myself in order to give it a width and height? I assumed it would size itself around its contents, much like, say, a `div`.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle link by the way. This is the archetypal helpful answer.

Comment: @David It won't size itself around the contents because the 'contents' are an infinite plane ;)